# $x_n=\sin(x_{n-1}),x_{0}\in (0,\pi)$, find limit $x_{n}\sqrt{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Choose $x_0\in (0,\pi)$ arbitrarily, and define a sequence $x_n$ iteratively by $x_n=\sin(x_{n-1})$ for each $n\ge 1$.
Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}\cdot x_n =\sqrt{3}$.

I am not able to solve this. Not even a single idea which can help came to my mind. So any hint or solution.

Comment: I think you should use square brackets for the range of numbers $x_0$ can start from. Because I don't think $x_0$ = 0 or $\pi$ works. Maybe it's $x_0 \in \, ]0, \pi[$?

Comment: Hmmm, that's true..but any idea

Comment: @QuestionAsker Usual brackets have exactly this purpose. $x_0 \neq 0, \pi$.

Comment: @Crostul My bad - am unfamiliar with that

Comment: @QuestionAsker no, it's correct as it stands, since $[0,\pi]$ would mean you include these two points, $(0,\pi)$ means you don't